# too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

My project successfully compiles on the Win32 platform. Now I have to turn off the 'classic Borland compiler' because I'd like to use Designated Initializers like this:

```
struct test_s test = { .first = 1, .third = 3, .second = 2 };
```

When the 'classic Borland compiler' is turned off, I've got the following error message;

```
[bcc32c Error] codecvt(131): too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
  std_compat.h(7): macro 'max' defined here
```

I have the same problem on the Win64 target.

My project compiles without problems in C++Builder 10.1, but when I try to compile in 10.4, I have this problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How is test_s defined? Designated initialization order must match the declaration order.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the question. Something in the line where the error is reported contains the token `max`. Which is a macro (probably defined in the standard library). Which apparently expands to gibberish there. Are you trying to also name something `max` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by removing the following include from some of my include files and using it from cpp only. However it works in 10.1 and very simple .

```
//- contents of std_compat.h -----------------------------------------------------

#ifndef std_compatH
#define std_compatH

#define min( a, b ) (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b)
#define max( a, b ) (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)

#endif
```

Comment: The standard C++ library has [`std::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) algorithms, you should be using those instead of such preprocessor macros.